# String compare files names with numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have two or more files that I want to compare. I'm looking for the file with the highest value. Whats a short and sweet method to get the most current file with this naming scheme:

```
update_12345.log
update_23456.log
update_34567.log <- get this one
```

I could obviously break it down and compare the numbers but then I have to keep track of which file I'm referring to. Trying to avoid creating unnecessary operations if possible.

Comment: There is no way to do this *except* breaking down the name, finding the highest number.

Comment: Maybe show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: I'm just looking for better suggestions... breaking it down is trivial the code for it is trivial.

Comment: If they're always going to be in that format, then just add them to a SortedList and get the max value. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can order a List and it will give you the order you are requiring

```
var myList = new List<string>()
{
    "update_12345.log", "update_23456.log", "update_34567.log"
};
var lastString = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
String folder = Directory.GetFiles(mypath).OrderBy(f => f).Last()
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a *trick*. Imagine, that you have

```
  update_12345.log
  update_23456.log
  update_34567.log  // <- actual solution
  update_5.log      // <- note this number
```

since `5` is less than `34567` then `update_34567.log` is still the answer; however, if you sort the names *lexicographically* (as .Net does by default) you'll have `update_5.log` as an answer. If it's your case, then a quick solution can be

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);
...
String[] updates = new String[] {
  "update_12345.log",
  "update_23456.log",
  "update_34567.log", 
  "update_5.log" 
}

// smart sorting, "-" for backward sorting
Array.Sort(updates, (left, right) => -StrCmpLogicalW(left, right));

String result = updates[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since results can be different based on cultures, you need to sort using numbers only. And you can do it without "loosing track" of wich file is which

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] files = 
        new string[] { "update_12345.log", "update_23456.log", "update_34567.log" };

    var sorted = files
      .Select(f => {var a = f.Split("_.".ToCharArray()); 
                    return new { name = f, number = a[1]};} )
      .OrderByDescending(fnn => Convert.ToInt64(fnn.number));

    // Print all
    sorted.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.name) );
    // Print Top 1 [1]
    Console.WriteLine(sorted.ToList().First().name);
    // Print Top 1 [2]
    Console.WriteLine(sorted.ToList().Take(1).Single().name);
}
```

Output:

> update_34567.log
>   update_23456.log
>   update_12345.log
>
> update_34567.log
>
> update_34567.log